# Annotating closure parameter foces use of Higher-Rank Trait Bounds

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

In this naive snippet ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c9879ab38819ef6f46354c7406d5e90)), using the unannotated version of the closure does not compile, while annotating with the type does:

```rust
fn bounded(items: &[&u8]) -> bool {
    items.iter().all(|item| **item <= 10)
}

fn check(check_function: &dyn Fn(&[&u8]) -> bool, items: &[&u8]) -> bool {
    check_function(items)
}

fn main() {
    let a = [1, 45, 7, 2];
    let b = [&a[2], &a[0], &a[0]];
    
    let func = |items| bounded(items); // E0308
    // let func = |items: &[&u8]| bounded(items);
    
    println!("{:?}", check(&func, &b));
}
```

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:28:35
   |
28 |     println!("{:?}", Checker::new(&func).check(&b));
   |                                   ^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected trait `for<'a, 'b> Fn<(&'a [&'b u8],)>`
              found trait `Fn<(&[&u8],)>`
note: this closure does not fulfill the lifetime requirements
  --> src/main.rs:25:16
   |
25 |     let func = |items| bounded(items);
   |                ^^^^^^^

error: implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
  --> src/main.rs:28:35
   |
28 |     println!("{:?}", Checker::new(&func).check(&b));
   |                                   ^^^^^ implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
   |
   = note: closure with signature `fn(&'2 [&u8]) -> bool` must implement `FnOnce<(&'1 [&u8],)>`, for any lifetime `'1`...
   = note: ...but it actually implements `FnOnce<(&'2 [&u8],)>`, for some specific lifetime `'2`

error: implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
  --> src/main.rs:28:35
   |
28 |     println!("{:?}", Checker::new(&func).check(&b));
   |                                   ^^^^^ implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
   |
   = note: closure with signature `fn(&[&'2 u8]) -> bool` must implement `FnOnce<(&[&'1 u8],)>`, for any lifetime `'1`...
   = note: ...but it actually implements `FnOnce<(&[&'2 u8],)>`, for some specific lifetime `'2`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 3 previous errors
```

I am now aware that I could use `fn` to store a function pointer directly ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da869a14d9989978fd60d7c936de0120)), but want to investigate the error caused from using closures.

```rust
fn check(check_function: fn(&[&u8]) -> bool, items: &[&u8]) -> bool {
    check_function(items)
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320703/wrong-lifetime-inference-for-closure-with-implicit-types) question also deals with the explicit annotation of the closure compiling, but is about the borrow checker, whereas I do not borrow twice in my code.

---

I have read the Rustonomicon's [lifetime chapters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetimes.html), as well as the Book's [lifetime chapters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html?highlight=lifetime#lifetime-annotation-syntax). I roughly understand the mechanics, but need help with the conceptual reasoning for lifetime elision, and specific/general lifetimes.

1. Why isn't `&'c [&'c u8]` sufficient for `&'a [&'b u8]`?

The latter is from lifetime elision, but it seems to me like if `'a` is invalidated, `'b` is also invalidated, so any function receiving the former (which gets the shortest lifetime of the two) should also work.

I don't think this is a over-conservative check, since the Rustonomicon mentions that references can be re-initialized. Here is my attempt explaining why ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0f8431dd9baae785613e4b8e4752e1f2)):

```rust
fn print(vec: &[&u8]) {
    println!("{vec:?}")
}

fn main() {
    let x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut y = vec![&x[1], &x[2], &x[3]];
    print(&y); // &y is &'b [&'a u8, &'a u8, &'a u8]
    y.insert(0, &x[0]); // lifetime of 'b is invalidated and 'c is initialized
    print(&y); // &y is &'d [&'c u8, &'a u8, &'a u8, &'a u8]
}
```

Although this does re-initialize the reference, it seems like I could still run both `print` functions by binding the all references from `&y` to the shorter lifetime(`'b` and `'d` respectively).

2. What are the lifetimes of the value captured by the closure?

Using rust-analyzer, it correctly deduces that the type of `items` is `&[&u8]`. Looking at the errors, this is also the type captured:

> found trait `Fn<(&[&u8],)>`

But referring to [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) and [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747620/lifetime-of-references-in-closures), it seems like `Fn` should be desugared to some `for<...> Fn(...)`, this isn't done to `func` here.

The other errors also hint at the closure being implemented for some specific lifetime (the lifetime of `main()`?). Is this the reason why no explicit lifetime marker is given?

Related: Lifetime elision/annotation [cannot be applied to closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843906/why-can-i-not-return-a-reference-from-a-closure).

3. Why does annotating the closure with `&[&u8]` work?

This one I don't have many clues about. I'm guessing that this allows the compiler to explicitly bind the captured value to a HRTB, and that allows the closure to be general enough.

Comment: I imagine it's to do with the fact that "the compiler will infer one concrete type for each of [the closure's] parameters and for their return value". I don't know if "concrete type" is well-defined in the spec, but it could very well mean `&'2 [&u8]` for some concrete `'2`. Annotating the closure leads the compiler to instead infer the more general `for<'1> &'1 [&u8]`.

Comment: "Why isn't &'c [&'c u8] sufficient for &'a [&'b u8]?" It is (for elided lifetimes) but the lifetime elision rule is that each reference gets a unique lifetime. There's no need to special case slices here. The `'b: 'a` bound will be inferred automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

---

I believe that isaactfa is correct in that the compiler is inferring the wrong type without the annotation, and when you annotate it, the compiler is able to infer a more correct type.

It is also possible to get it to infer the correct types by adding lifetimes to `check` instead of adding an annotation to the closure as seen [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7eb8beea7981042b958db26f32d3c18b). Adding these annotations helps the compiler to realize that your arguments live long enough to be used by the the closure, and to figure out the closure's lifetime.

```rust
fn check<'b1, 'b2, 'a1: 'b1, 'a2: 'b2>(check_function: &dyn Fn(&'b1 [&'b2 u8]) -> bool, items: &'a1 [&'a2 u8]) -> bool {
    check_function(items)
}
```

### Correction

---

There is however some information that isn't correct in your post that I do want to correct real quick:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut y = vec![&x[1], &x[2], &x[3]];
    print(&y); // &y is &'b [&'a u8, &'a u8, &'a u8]
    y.insert(0, &x[0]); // lifetime of 'b is invalidated and 'c is initialized
    print(&y); // &y is &'d [&'c u8, &'a u8, &'a u8, &'a u8]
}
```

In this snippet, you write that the lifetime of `&y` is of type `&'d [&'c u8, &'a u8, &'a u8, &'a u8]`, however this isn't accurate. It is still of the type `&'d [&'a u8]`. Pushing the value `&x[0]` does not introduce a new lifetime, because you are referencing `x`, just like you did when you initialized `y`. You can verify this by putting the insert line into another block. In order for it to compile, the lifetime `'c` has to be as long (or longer) than the lifetime `'a`, because `y` is used later. Running this on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1198a87037cfb53e82fffc0777599964) shows that the borrow is not related to the `&` itself, but to the lifetime of the object that is being borrowed from.

```
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let mut y = vec![&x[1], &x[2], &x[3]];
println!("{:?}", &y);
{
    // If the lifetime was related to this `&` and not `x`,
    // then this wouldn't be able to compile because
    // the `&` is within a shorter scope.
    y.insert(0, &x[0]);
}
println!("{:?}", &y);
```

If you were to instead push a reference of an item inside the block, then the lifetime of `y` could be shortened:

```
fn main() {
    let x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut y = vec![&x[1], &x[2], &x[3]];
    println!("{:?}", &y);
    {
        let inner = [1,2,3,4];
        y.insert(0, &inner[0]);
        println!("{:?}", &y);
    }
    // Requires that `y` and all it's elements live as long as `x`, because
    // `y` was initialized with values from `x`.
    println!("{:?}", &y);
}
```

This fails because `inner` doesn't live long enough. If you were to comment out the last `println!` then it would run, because the lifetime of the borrows of `x` (inside of `y`) can be shorted to the lifetime of `inner`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With regards to "... the borrow is [related to] the lifetime of the object that is being borrowed from", would annotating the lifetimes of `x` [like so](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0900b48c6e704c8c1406d5e1cc1d50ca) be correct? What I'm understanding is that since `x` in my original question is immutable, all references have the same lifetime, but that is no longer the case if `x` is changed, like how the two references to `y` are of different lifetimes.