# closure without type annotation cause borrow mutable more than once at a time error

Tags: rust

I have some situation when I deal with closure

the problem is in the code below

I think the each closure would have each scope and each scope would drop after the closure was used.
So I don't borrow mut reference more than once at a time,
and it actually run correct.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut st = "add: ".to_string();
    let add_one = |str| add(str,1);
    let add_two = |str| add(str,2);
    add_one(&mut st);
    add_two(&mut st);
    println!("add: {:?} ",st);
}
fn add(str: &mut String,num:i32) {
    str.push_str(&num.to_string())
}
```

but when I want to use the add_one closure again

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut st = "add: ".to_string();
    let add_one = |str| add(str,1);
    let add_two = |str| add(str,2);
    add_one(&mut st);
    //add_two(&mut st); for clearly I comment this line
    add_one(&mut st);
    println!("add: {:?} ",st);
}
fn add(str: &mut String,num:i32) {
    str.push_str(&num.to_string())
}
```

the compiler show this error

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `st` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:13:13
   |
11 |     add_one(&mut st);
   |             ------- first mutable borrow occurs here
12 |     //add_two(&mut st); for clearly I comment this line
13 |     add_one(&mut st);
   |     ------- ^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     |
   |     first borrow later used by call
```

I think this problem is same as this
[Compiler complains about multiple mutable borrows, but how?](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnrust/comments/jte3jh/compiler_complains_about_multiple_mutable_borrows/?xpromo_edp=enabled)

Yes,I could solve this by explicity specify the type on parameter,

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut st = "add: ".to_string();
    let add_one = |str:&mut String| add(str,1);//explicit  type
    let add_two = |str| add(str,2);
    add_one(&mut st);
    add_two(&mut st); 
    add_one(&mut st);
    println!("add: {:?} ",st);
//add: "add: 121"
}
fn add(str: &mut String,num:i32) {
    str.push_str(&num.to_string())
}
```

But I still do not know why compiler think this as different situation.

Could someone can explain more detail about this problem?
I would appreciate your answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: there is no clear rule about what "should" compile when it come to this kind of code, in future we can hope compiler would compile all your sniped, but for now it's look compiler can't guess right.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76500115/annotating-closure-parameter-foces-use-of-higher-rank-trait-bounds) might be related (doesn't have a 100% conclusive answer either), but I believe Rust infers the closure's type to be `FnMut(&'1 mut String)` where `'1` is some _concrete_ lifetime. So when you try to call it again, it thinks both mutable refs have the same lifetime which is a borrow check error. When you annotate it with `&mut String`, it infers the correct `for<'a> FnMut(&'a mut String)` instead.

Comment: It doesn’t save you much, but you could give the type as `&mut _` and it will compile.